# Accessing Google Groups Services on Google Apps Script in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I'm trying to work out if it is possible to use Google Apps Scripts inside Google App Engine?

And if there is a tutorial in doing this out there ?

Through reading Google's App Script site I get the feeling that you can only use app scripts inside Google Apps like Drive, Docs etc?

What I would like to do is to be able to use the Groups Service that is in GAS inside GAE to Create, delete and only show the groups that a person is in, all inside my GAE App.

Thanks

Comment: If you need a user to log-in - then luke's idea looks best. If there is no login issue, you should be able to use HTMLService in GAS to return the data from GAS to GAE via a url fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. AS and GAE are totally different things and won't work together.
What you can really do is (abstract):

1. write an AS that does what you need
2. redirect from GAE to the AS url to make sure that the user logs-in/grants permissions.
3. perform what you needed to do with AS
4. send back the user to GAE with a bunch of parameters if you need to

Answer (score 0):

If you need GAE in Google Apps script, you can write a webservice in GAE using UrlFetch in Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlfetch

To give you an example: I created an Apps Script to get report data (json) from an appengine webservice. This data is added to a google apps spreadsheet.